# Only on Chrome I got this error: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When I did load jQuery on Chrome I will receive this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor"

On rest browsers (IE, Mozilla) it's working fine. Here is couple screen shots from my PC. It's a same error.

[image: first example]
<sub>(source: [vaziuoju.lt](http://vaziuoju.lt/bugs/Untitled.png))</sub>

[image: second example]

Code:

```
$(Document).ready (function () {

    $("p.warning").hide();

    $( "#newAdsForm" ).submit(function( event ) {


        var vailidEmail = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;

        var vardas = $("#vardas").val();                    var vardasTest = false;
        var vardas = vardas.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
        var pastas = $("#pastas").val();                    var pastasTest = false;
        var phone = $("#phone").val();                      var phoneTest = false;
        var kada = $("#inputField").val();                  var kadaTest = false;
        var kaina = $("#kaina").val();                      var kainaTest = false;
        var kaina = kaina.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
        var skelbimas = $("#skelbimas").val();              var skelbimasTest = false;
        var skelbimas = skelbimas.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');

        if (vardas == "") {
            $("p#vardas").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                $("p#vardas").text ("Vardas būtinas!");
            });
            $("p#vardas").fadeIn("fast");
            vardasTest = false;
        } else {
            $("p#vardas").fadeOut("fast");
            vardasTest = true;
        }

        if (pastas == "") {
            $("p#pastas").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                $("p#pastas").text ("El. paštas būtinas!");
            });
            $("p#pastas").fadeIn("fast");
            pastasTest = false;
        } else if (!pastas.match(vailidEmail)) {
            $("p#pastas").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                $("p#pastas").text("Negaliojantis pašto adresas!");
            });
            $("p#pastas").fadeIn("fast");
            pastasTest = false;
        } else {
            $("p#pastas").fadeOut("fast");
            pastasTest = true;
        }

        if (phone == "") {
            $("p#phone").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                $("p#phone").text ("Telefono numeris būtinas!");
            });
            $("p#phone").fadeIn("fast");
            phoneTest = false;
        }
        else if (!phone.match(/^[0-9-+]+$/)) {
            $("p#phone").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                $("p#phone").text ("Neteisingas Telefono numeris!");
            });
            $("p#phone").fadeIn("fast");
            phoneTest = false;
        } else  {
            $("p#phone").fadeOut("fast");
            phoneTest = true;
        }

        var comp = kada.split('-');
        if ((comp[0].length != 4) || (comp[1].length != 2) || (comp[2].length != 2) || (kada.length != 10)) {
            $("p#kada").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                $("p#kada").text ("Blogai nurodyta data!");
            });
            $("p#kada").fadeIn("fast");
            kadaTest = false;
        } else if ((!comp[0].match(/^\d+$/)) || (!comp[1].match(/^\d+$/)) || (!comp[2].match(/^\d+$/))) {
            $("p#kada").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                $("p#kada").text ("Blogai nurodyta data2!");
            });
            $("p#kada").fadeIn("fast");
            kadaTest = false;
        } else {
            $("p#kada").fadeOut("fast");
            kadaTest = true;
        }

        if (kaina.length != 0) {


            var number = /^\-{0,1}(?:[0-9]+){0,1}(?:\.[0-9]+){0,1}$/i;
            var regex = RegExp(number);

            if (!regex.test(input) && input.length>0) {
                $("p#kaina").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                    $("p#kaina").text ("Neteisinga kaina!");
                });
                $("p#kaina").fadeIn("fast");
                kainaTest = false;
            } else {
                $("p#kaina").fadeOut("fast");
                kainaTest = true;
            } 
        } else {
            $("p#kaina").fadeOut("fast");
            kainaTest = true;
        } 

        if (vardasTest && pastasTest && phoneTest && kadaTest && kainaTest) return true;
        else return false;

    });

});
```

Part of HTML code

```
   <tr><td>Vardas</td><td><input type = "text" class = "newAdd" name = "vardas" id = "vardas" <?php if (isset($_SESSION ['vardas'])) echo "value = '".$_SESSION ['vardas']; ?>'/><p class = "warning" id = "vardas">Vardas būtinas!</p></td></tr>
```

Any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: Showing us the jQuery source code (in a screenshot, no less) isn't very useful. The issue is likely in **your** code, when you're calling a jQuery function in an unexpected manner.

Comment: What in your code is triggering this code?

Comment: Already posted my code. Sorry for that

Comment: Could you also post the html?

Comment: What line in *your* script causes the error?  If you don't know then either step through it with the debugger, or put some debug messages in so you can see where the script stops.

Comment: "Any ideas how I can fix it?" Learn to use the debugger in Chrome.  You can set it to drop into debug mode on all exceptions, examine the current state of the callstack, and evaluate expressions and variables within the current execution context.  We can't do that from here.

Comment: Archer: i delete everything after $("p.warning").hide(); and still same error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should try it with a lowercase

> "d"

```
$(document).ready(function(){...
```

javascript **is** case-sensitive once a variable is set

Comment: Just tried it here and it's exactly that.  What a bizarre and unhelpful error message.

Comment: Thats perfect!!! Stupid mistyping. Thanks !!!

Comment: no problem, js is case-sensitive, once a variable is set ;)

Comment: @Archer it's a coincidence, because `Document` is an actually existing function. Normally you would get a more descriptive error message when writing a variable name with wrong case (reference error).