# jQuery Code not working On Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

**jQuery code**

```
$(Document).ready(function() {
    var $download = $('#navbar li:nth-child(1)');
    var $about_us = $('#navbar li:nth-child(2)');

    $download.mouseenter(function() {
        $download.fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    });

    $about_us.mouseenter(function() {
        $about_us.fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    });

    $('#navbar li').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#navbar li').fadeTo('fast',1);
    });
});
```

With this code I am trying to make parts of a list darker when you hover. it works in Firefox but not on chrome, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use `$download` or `$about_us`... This is not PHP... It should only be `var download` and `var about_us`

Comment: @kakashihatake2 - A common naming convention is `$variable` when the variable references an element that is a jquery object. For instance, `$body = $('body'); $body.css('color', 'red')`.

Comment: Duplicate of **[only on chrome i got this error: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779153/only-on-chrome-i-got-this-error-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-constructor)**

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is case-sensitive, so you'll need to use `document` instead of `Document`; they are two separate things in Chrome.

`Document` appears to be a constructor for something in Chrome, but I'm not sure about its usage.

Comment: @AmitJoki In Google Chrome using `$(Document)` will give error : `Uncaught TypeError: Object function Document() { [native code] } has no method 'apply' http://jsfiddle.net/WhLzL/

Comment: @AmitJoki Not according to my Chrome web console. `Document` has no `onreadystatelistener`. `document` does.

Comment: k. I'll take back my word.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the OP's bug and fix it just by changing `Document` to `document`:

http://jsfiddle.net/rn5v7/4/ will work on Firefox but not Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/rn5v7/5/ will work on both Firefox and Chrome.

The standard way to use DOM ready handler is, as on [jQuery's doc](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... })
```

or the shorthand:

```
$(function() { ... });
```

Note that as seen on Chrome, `Document` is a constructor function.  It is the base class of `HTMLDocument`, which is the class for the object `document`.

```
document.__proto__ === HTMLDocument.prototype  // => true
HTMLDocument.prototype.__proto__ === Document.prototype  // => true
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `$(Document)` should be changed to low class `$(document)`. Then more facts are below.

> For Chrome, do not expect $ is always `jQuery`.

You can put `$` into console to check if it returns default `ƒ $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }`, if yes means $ is not defined for `jQuery`.

Luckily that we have below ways to try:

1. **Solve the conflict of using `$`, let it be `jQuery` without any ambiguity**

Firstly, you can put this code snippet

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js";  /* Include any online jquery library you need */
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
```

into the Console, 
then put `$.noConflict` into console, if it not returns `undefined`, but returns `ƒ (t){return e.$===w&&(e.$=Kt),t&&e.jQuery===w&&(e.jQuery=Jt),w}`, it means `$` is not defined for `JQuery` now.

Next you can continue to input your regional code, then you will find it works well now.

**Refer**: https://blog.wplauncher.com/run-jquery-in-chrome-console/

2. **Using `.js` file instead in Chrome, then debug the JavaScript file.**

**Refer:** [Chrome DevTools Snippets](http://bgrins.github.io/devtools-snippets/)